# the fastest way to pick the Nth element of a hash

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a big hashtable (array with string indexes) and looking for a function that *quickly* picks the first (ideally, also Nth) element from it. `array_shift()` and `reset()` are too slow for my needs.

**UPDATE**: i'm also not looking for a reference-based solution, the function should accept expressions as in `get_first(some_func_returning_array())`

**ANSWER** array_slice method (kudos Gumbo) seems to be the winner. Complete benchmarking code

```
function bigary($n) {
    $a = array();
    $s = range('A', 'Z');
    do {
        shuffle($s);
        $a[substr(implode('', $s), rand(10, 20))] = $n;
    } while(--$n);
    return $a;
}

function timeit($name, $fn) {
    global $results;

    $loops = 1000;
    $size  = 5432;

    static $a;
    if(!$a) $a = bigary($size);

    $t = microtime(1);
    for($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++)
        $b = $fn($a);
    $results[$name] = microtime(1) - $t;
}

timeit('dummy', function ($a) { 
    // benchmark php function call overhead
});

timeit('array_shift', function ($a) { 
    return array_shift($a); 
});

timeit('reset', function ($a) { 
    return reset($a); 
});

timeit('foreach', function ($a) { 
    foreach($a as $b) return $b;
});

timeit('keys', function ($a) { 
    $b = array_keys($a); 
    return $a[$b[0]];
});

timeit('values', function ($a) { 
    $b = array_values($a); 
    return $b[0];
});

timeit('slice', function ($a) { 
    $b = array_slice($a, 0, 1); 
    return reset($b);
});

asort($results);

foreach($results as $name => $time)
    printf("%20s = %.3f\n", $name, $time);
```

Results:

```
           dummy = 0.393
           slice = 0.433
          values = 0.824
         foreach = 0.929
           reset = 0.935
     array_shift = 0.954
            keys = 1.371
```

Comment: If `reset()` is honestly too slow for you, I'm wondering if you shouldn't maybe look into using a different language - specifically, something compiled, not interpreted? I know that's easier said than done, but I'm honestly not sure you can get significantly faster than that function while staying within PHP's capabilities. (Though I'll happily be proven wrong.)

Comment: Your benchmark is flawed. The slow part is the calling of the anonymous function. Without that, on my computer, `reset` is < 0.001, `array_slice` is < 0.002

Comment: @sterofrog, you don't 'need' it to be, you 'want' it to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) to get an array of just the *n*-th item and [`array_pop`](http://php.net/array_pop) to finally get it:

```
$nthItem = array_pop(array_slice($arr, $n, 1));
```

Comment: +1 for `array_slice()`, which is great - ...but if even `reset()` is too slow for the stereofrog, this is going to be brutal. :[

Answer (score 4):

Your benchmark may be flawed, since:

```
$fn = function ($a) { 
    return array_shift($a); 
};
timeit('array_shift', $fn);
```

> array_shift = 1.242 (5432)

and

```
timeit('array_shift', array_shift);
```

> array_shift = 0.026 (4433)

but also

```
$fn = function ($a) { } 
timeit('empty lambda', $fn);
```

> empty lambda = 0.501 (0)

That being said, another possible solution:

```
$v = array_values($a);
return $v[ $index ];
```

Sample Code:

```
$t = microtime(1);
$v = array_values($a); // cached
while($loops--) {
    $b = $v[$loops];
}
```

> array_values = 0.002 (5432)

Comment: +1 for `array_values`. If you need lots of `nth` values in a single execution, then you'd only have to run it once, and you can just always take the `$v[$n]` element.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get any faster than `reset()`/`end()` for first/last element.

As for N'th element, I can't think of anything better than this:

```
function (&$hashmap, $n) {
    $keys = array_keys($hashmap);
    return $hashmap[$keys[$n]];
}
```

Of course for performance this can tuned to have a pre-cached `$keys` array (if hashmap doesn't change very often). In that case maybe even 0'th element retrieval may be faster than with `reset()`

Comment: According to [comments on PHP.net](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php#96090) it seems that these functions use somewhat different implementations for int-indexed and associative arrays. So there is a tiny chance that I'm wrong (for your sake, I hope so too). Could you benchmark it with the above solution? Would be interesting to know

Comment: Sorry, haven't noticed your benchmark code before. It seems that my solution lost to `array_shift` by a score 1.4s VS 2.4s. A pre-cached key solution achieved 0.7s (and that's using random access, i.e. Nth element), but it only calculated `$keys` once, so it's not very realistic case, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first:

```
function array_first(array $array) {
     foreach ($array as $value) return $value;
     return false;
}
```

And although I haven't tested this for speed, you could try using `array_values()` to convert the array to a numerically indexed array.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first element try to reset the array's pointer with reset ( array &$array ).
Then get the current value with current(). To get the Nth element use the end(), to set the pointer to the last item. At this point you should be able to get the Nth item with current().

Comment: Heads-up: `reset()` and `end()` also return the first and last element's value (respectively), so calling `current()` should not be necessary.

Comment: The php manual says that reset/end will return values, not reference. But if they do I can't see why is it bad for you. @stereofrog